# A family of open sets of measure $<1$ such that the union of any two has measure $\ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Can someone give me a few hints about how to solve this problem?

Let  $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on the real line and $P$ the collection of all the open sets $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $m(U)<1$. Let $Q \subseteq P$ such that for each couple $V_1, V_2 \in Q$, with $V_1 \neq V_2$, we have $m(V_1 \cup V_2) \geq 1$.  Show that $Q$ is at most countable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses a little bit of $L^1$ theory. I admit that OP is possibly unaware of $L^1$ theory at this point, but I think this may help demystify the problem.

By the assumption, whenever $V, W \in Q$ are distinct, we have

$$ \| \mathbf{1}_V - \mathbf{1}_W \|_{L^1} = m(V \cup W) - m(V \cap W) \geq 1 - \min\{ m(V), m(W) \} > 0, \tag{1}$$

where $\mathbf{1}_V$ is the indicator function of $V$. Now for each $V \in Q$ define $\epsilon_V = \frac{1}{3}(1 - m(V))$ and consider open balls of the form

$$ B_V := \{ f \in L^1(\Bbb{R}) : \| f - \mathbf{1}_V \|_{L^1} < \epsilon_V \}. $$

Then $\mathcal{C} = \{ B_V : V \in Q \}$ is a family of *disjoint* open balls in $L^1(\Bbb{R})$. Indeed, this follows by observing that for each distinct $V, W \in Q$ inequality $\text{(1)}$ yields

$$ \| \mathbf{1}_V - \mathbf{1}_W \|_{L^1}
> \epsilon_V + \epsilon_W. $$

But since $L^1(\Bbb{R})$ is separable, $\mathcal{C}$ is at most countable. Therefore $Q$ is at most countable.

Comment: +1.  From (1) we see that  $1_V$  is not in the closure of $\{1_W :W\in Q\land W\ne V\},$ so  $Q$ is a discrete subspace of $L^1.$  A discrete subspace of a separable metric space is countable.

Comment: @user254665 Right. The proof in this answer can be made shorter as you pointed in your comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!